Anscombe-Aumann Trick
I'm going over an exercise concerning the 'trick' used in the construction of the subjective-expected-utility representation of Auscombe and Aumann. I think the exercise is from some textbook of Kreps but I'm not sure from where exactly it comes.
Let $X$ be an arbitrary finite set of objects, and let $Z$ be the set of all subsets of $X$. Assume a decision maker has complete and transitive preferences over $Z$. We immediately have a continuous utility representation $u:Z\to \mathbb{R}$, but we'd like to get more structure in the representation.
There are two subparts to this question and I'm not sure exactly what I am meant to find in each, so would appreciate someone verifying my answer.
The sub-questions are,

First, expand the domain of preferences to the collection of all probability distributions over $Z$. Denote this as $P:=\Delta(Z)$. One can make $P$ a mixture space. Assume the expanded preferences satisfy the mixture-space theorem requirements. The set $P$ is an expansion of $Z$ in the sense that degenerate lotteries in $P$ replicate outcomes from $Z$. Does this pin down the structure of $u$?
Second, expand the domain of preferences to $Q:=[0,1]^X$, where the interpretation of an element $q\in Q$ is that, if the decision maker chooses $q$, then $q(x)$ is the probability that the decision maker gets $x$ in the subset of objects out of $X$ that they receive. Again, this can be considered as a mixture space, and we assume the expanded preferences over $Q$ satisfy the mixture-space theorem requirements. The set $Q$ is an expansion of $Z$ as each element $z\in Z$ can be identified with $q\in Q$ that gives probability $1$ to elements $x\in z$ and $0$ probability to $x\not\in z$. Does this pin down the form of $u$? (Hint: yes, it does. You should show that there is $U:X\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $u(z)=\sum_{x\in z} U(x)$).

For part (1), we can directly appeal to the vNM representation theorem to get a function $W:P\to \mathbb{R}$ representing preferences with form, $$W(p)=\sum_{z\in Z} p(z)u(z)$$ I think all this gets us is that $u(z)$ is unique up to affine transformation and doesn't say anything beyond this.
For part (2), I proceed as in the proof of the Anscombe-Aumann representation. By the mixture-space theorem, there is $V:Q\to \mathbb{R}$ representing preferences such that, for $\alpha\in [0,1]$ and $q_1,q_2\in Q$, $$V(\alpha q_1+(1-\alpha)q_2)=\alpha V(q_1)+(1-\alpha)V(q_2)$$ I shall call this property the 'linear' property. Now, fix any $q^*=(q_1^*,q_2^*,\dots , q_{\vert X\vert}^*)\in Q$. For any other $q=(q_1,q_2,\dots , q_{\vert X\vert})\in Q$ define $$\begin{align}q^1&=(q_1,q_2^*,\dots , q_{\vert X \vert}^*) \\
q^2&=(q_1^*,q_2, q_3^*,\dots , q_{\vert X \vert}^*) \\
& \  \ \vdots \\
q^n &= (q_1^*,q_2^*,\dots , q_{n-1}^*,q_n,q_{n+1}^*,\dots , q_{\vert X\vert}^*) \\
& \  \ \vdots  \\ 
q^{\vert X\vert} &=(q_1^*,q_2^*, \dots , q_{\vert X\vert -1}^*, q_{\vert X \vert}) \end{align}$$
Then, enumerating $X$ as $\{1,2,\dots , \vert X\vert \}$, $$\frac{1}{\vert X\vert} \sum_{x\in X}q^x = \frac{1}{\vert X\vert} q+\frac{\vert X\vert -1}{\vert X\vert} q^*$$ By the linear property of $V$, $$\begin{align} \frac{1}{\vert X\vert} \sum_{x\in X}V(q^x) &= \frac{1}{\vert X\vert} V(q)+\frac{\vert X\vert -1}{\vert X\vert} V(q^*) \\
V(q) &= \sum_{x\in X}\left[V(q^x) -\frac{\vert X\vert -1}{\vert X\vert}V(q^*)\right] \\
V(q) &= \sum_{x\in X} V(q_1^*,q_2^*,\dots , q_{x-1}^*,q_x,q_{x+1}^*,\dots , q_{\vert X\vert}^*)- \dots \\
& \qquad \dots - \frac{\vert X\vert-1}{\vert X\vert}V(q_1^*,q_2^*,\dots, q_{\vert X\vert}^*)\end{align}$$ For each $x\in X$, define $V_x:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ as $$V_x(s)=V(q_1^*,q_2^*,\dots , q_{x-1}^*,s,q_{x+1}^*,\dots , q_{\vert X\vert}^*) - \frac{\vert X\vert-1}{\vert X\vert}V(q_1^*,q_2^*,\dots, q_{\vert X\vert}^*)$$ So, $$V(q)=\sum_{x\in X} V_x(q_x)$$ Pick $z\in Z$. Define $\tilde{q}\in Q$ as $$\tilde{q}(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if } x\in z \\
0 & \text{ o/w}  \end{cases}$$ Then, the linear property of $V$ implies each $V_x$ has the linear property. Normalise $V(0)=0$. This implies $V_x(0)=0$ also by the linear property of each.
Since both $u$ and $V$ represent the same preferences over $Z$, $u(z)=V(\tilde{q})$. Thus, $$\begin{align} u(z)&=\sum_{x\in X} V_x(\tilde{q}_x) \\
&= \sum_{x\in z}V_x(1) +\sum_{x\not\in z} V_x(0) \\
&= \sum_{x\in z}V_x(1)  \end{align}$$ define $U(x)=V_x(1)$ to get the desired representation.
Does my proof make sense? I am most unsure about part (1) and whether there is anything more we can say about the structure of $u$ and also the normalisation of $V(0)=0$ part. Finally, why does the approach in part (2) work better than in part (1)? I don't have any intuition for why the Anscombe-Aumann trick works for $Q$ but not $P$. How far should we expand preferences in order to properly use the Anscombe-Ausmann trick?
